# XSLT - Issue getting sum of 2 values from same record

Tags: xml, sum, xslt-2.0

I am not able to get TotalPay value from below XML using XSLT. TotalPay is the sum of grosspay respective to number of Salary type present for each employee. Please see below XML data and Expected result that i am trying to achieve.

```
<---XML Data---->

<Payroll_Data>
<EmpId>1000</EmpId>
<FirstName>Mark</FirstName>
<LastName>Henry</LastName>
<Salary>
    <Type>B</Paytype>   
    <GrossPay>1000.50</GrossPay>
</Salary>
<Salary>
    <Type>X</Paytype>   
    <GrossPay>847.50</GrossPay>
</Salary>
</Payroll_Data>
<Payroll_Data>
<EmpId>1001</EmpId>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Diggle</LastName>
<Salary>
    <Type>B</Paytype>   
    <GrossPay>800.98</GrossPay>
</Salary>
<Salary>
    <Type>X</Paytype>   
    <GrossPay>630.50</GrossPay>
</Salary>
<Salary>
    <Type>Y</Paytype>   
    <GrossPay>600.50</GrossPay>
</Salary>

</Payroll_Data>

<----Expected Result---->
EmpId   FirstName   LastName    Type    GrossPay    TotalPay 
1000    Mark        Henry       B       1000.50     1847.98 (1000.50+847.48)
1000    Mark        Henry       X       847.48      1847.98
1001    John        Diggle      B       800.98      2031.98 (800.98+630.50+600.50)
1001    John        Diggle      X       630.50      2031.98
1001    John        Diggle      Y       600.50      2031.98
```

Comment: @martin.. it worked.. thanks for the help..

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple `sum(../Salary/GrossPay)` in the context of a `Salary` element as it seems the data is already grouped:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="//Salary"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Salary">
      <xsl:value-of select="../(EmpId, FirstName, LastName), Type, GrossPay, sum(../Salary/GrossPay)" separator="&#9;"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsW